# Tracker afterflush - meteor onrendered cannot read property

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, d3.js

I have been working with Meteor lately and ran into an issue with the iron router.
Im using d3.js to display data from MongoDb. I have setup publication-subscriptions. I used waitOn and action and also tried the onBefore without any success. 
Here is my code:

```
Router.map(function(){
this.route('consoleTemplate',{
    path: '/',
    template: 'consoleTemplate',

    waitOn: function(){
        return Meteor.subscribe('theOrganizations',terms);
    },

    action: function(){
        this.render('consoleTemplate');
    }
});
});

 Router.configure({
layoutTemplate: 'layout',
loadingTemplate: 'myLoading'
})
Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
```

consoleTemplate:

```
  <template name = "consoleTemplate">
  <h1>Admin Console</h1>
  <div class = "ui grid">
  <div class = "column">
  {{> table1}}
  </div>
  </div>
 <h1> Dashboard Analytics</h1>
 {{> graphContainer}}  
 </template>
```

where graphContainer and table1 are two subtemplates here.

I am rendering a graph with d3 in consoleTemplate using onRendered() and autoRun(). I get the error:'Exception from Tracker afterFlush function: cannot ready property of undefined'. I want the template to render after all the data is available.

Could someone advise on how to solve this? Much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us the code in the consoleTemplate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [meteorjs iron-router waitOn and using as data on rendered](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23575826/meteorjs-iron-router-waiton-and-using-as-data-on-rendered)

Comment: @JesperWe would the solution be then, to use just one of waiton or onrendered?

Comment: @SudheerJami added it in. Thanks.

Comment: Look at the accepted answer to that question! Don't this.render() until this.ready().